# Applying changes to model in master/detail scenario

Tags: wpf, master-detail, catel

I am developing an application using Catel with an master/detail architecture similar to `Catel.Examples.WPF.MasterDetail`. If I alter the properties of the current model in the Details view and then switch the current element in Master view, then all changes will be lost.

How can I change this behavior to keep all changes in the model when DataContext of Details view switches? Note that there is no way to add `Apply` button in Details view to explicitly apply changes.

Comment: show some code please

Comment: See https://catelproject.atlassian.net/browse/CTL-354, we will implement this as a native feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We implemented this native feature in Catel in the latest nightly build. If you don't feel comfortable using the latest nightly builds, you have the following option: don't decorate the model with the [Model] attribute.

For more information about the feature, see the original ticket:

https://catelproject.atlassian.net/browse/CTL-354

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I regularly update the Catel via Nuget,  so I'll wait for the latest nightly build.